# Logout user from other devices

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I want to automatically logout the user from other device once the user login to second device/browser.
Its a azure B2c Authenticated application. Is there a way to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: B2C tracks session on a per browser basis trough cookies. You cannot logout a user from different browser or devices. You need to implement an (additional) application wide session so that once wiped will force the user to re-authenticate regardless of the B2C SSO state. And the B2C sign out is not applicable to [Social Identity provider session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-overview#sign-out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Moving from Comments to answer)

B2C tracks session on a per browser basis trough cookies. You cannot logout a user from different browser or devices. You need to implement an (additional) application wide session so that once wiped will force the user to re-authenticate regardless of the B2C SSO state and the B2C sign out is not applicable to [Social Identity provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-overview#sign-out) session.